# Node & Express + jQuery: After authenticating save for session

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, authentication, express

I managed to make the user able to authenticate using name/pass. What I'm trying to achieve is, a disabled dropdown, when he authenticates, it gets enabled, then he can access files through the dropdown list. All of that I managed to make, one thing I'm puzzled with is how can I check if he already authenticated or not? So no one would inspect the html code and get access to the files.

I need a way to identify if a client (jQuery) has authenticated or not, something like session variables that ends with closing the page.

EDIT: I need it to be secured, I want to store a boolean that will allow the client to view all the log files.

Comment: Depends what your client side is. Is it all dynamic? When a user authenticates, does he do so via ajax or a full page submission?

Comment: jQuery ajax, ajax sends post with name/pass, then node handles checking and returns whether he managed to login or not.

Comment: OK, so your problem is maintaining the "is user logged in?" knowledge state throughout the life of the open window, on the browser side?

Answer (score 1):

Store this boolean in an Express session, and select which page to send to the client.

```
// enable session support
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'secret key for signed cookies'
}));

app.get('/foo', function(req, res) {
  req.session.authenticated = true;
});

app.get('/bar', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    // send page with files
  } else {
    // send page without files
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it secured? Can it be edited/hacked somehow? Remember, I want to store a boolean that if is true, the client will get access to everything. Also, what is the secret key?

Comment: If something's on the internet, then it's probably hackable. But yes, sessions are secure, and the secret key is for signed cookies.

Comment: So no one would be able to modify it's value?

Comment: It can only be modified server-side.